# Помогите советом о выборе ос

Tags: android, windows-ce

Здравствуйте.

Есть идея, сделать 3-4 интерактивных экрана, небольших размеров (примерно как фоторамка) и повесить их в частном доме, в разных комнатах/этажах. 
Функционал этих экранов предполагается такой:

- Передача сообщений между экранами
- Просмотр веб-камеры
- Выход в интернет (браузер)
- Вывод информации с локального сервер (температура воздуха и т.д.)
- Голосовые команды
- Определения личности по лицу (не обязательно)

Сам вопрос, на какой ОС это лучше делать?
Навигаторы часто делаю на Windows CE, или, может, лучше на Android, он вроде как более мультимедийный?
Так же не хотелось бы, чтобы ОС "кушала" много ресурсов.
Расскажите, на чём сделали бы вы и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

делал бы на Android потому, что   
1) Я знаю ,как сделать.  
2) На нем можно реализовать все, что вы хотите.  
3) много доступных (китайских) планшетов.

Comment: @metalurgus, Спасибо большое за ответ.  Не подскажите, возможно ли удалить (или хотя бы отключить) стандартные сервисы (такие как СМС,лаунчер и т.д.) ,они ведь не нужны для моей задумки ,но всегда присутствую в Android ,на сколько я знаю.

Comment: Можете сделать свое приложение лаунчером:)

А для того, что бы исключить стандартные приложения, скорее всего придется собирать свою прошивку.

Comment: Советую выбрать планшет, для которого есть cyanogenmod или опубликованы исходники прошивки, ну и есть root, тогда можно сделать с ним всё что угодно.
Хотя имея root-доступ можно удалить почти всё ненужное и без перекомпиляции прошивки.

Comment: @Mr_Epic в новой 5 версии Android есть возможность заблокировать для пользователя любые приложения. Т.е. создаете нового пользователя, который сможет запустить только разрешенные приложения.

Comment: для этого нужен как минимум root.    
Но как написал @KoVadim, вполне достаточно должно быть просто сделать приложение ланчером.